# Qt Quick QML MouseArea autorepeat on press

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Hopefully I'm not missing something obvious here.

I am writing an app and have made a zoom in button with an `Image` and a `MouseArea`. I need the button to repeat a method call after, say, every second to zoom in while holding the mouse button down. It isn't entirely obvious how to make this repeat. Right now I have:

```
Rectangle {
    id:zoomInBtn
    Image {
        id: zoomInImg
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: zoomIn.pressed ? ":/img/zoom_in_sel" : ":/img/zoom_in_unsel"
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: zoomIn
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: { cameraController.zoomIn(0.5); }
    }
```

I have also tried with

```
onPressAndHold: { cameraController.zoomIn(0.5); }
```

which does basically the same, although with a small delay as expected, but I need to repeat this action every second while the mouse button is held.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform the task you need you must use a [`Timer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html). the timer must remain active while the [`containsMouse`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#containsMouse-prop) is active. you must also enable [`triggeredOnStart`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html#triggeredOnStart-prop) to run immediately if the timer is activated.

```
Rectangle {
    id:zoomInBtn
    Image {
        id: zoomInImg
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: zoomIn.pressed ? ":/img/zoom_in_sel" : ":/img/zoom_in_unsel"
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: zoomIn
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        triggeredOnStart: true
        running: zoomIn.containsMouse
        onTriggered: cameraController.zoomIn(0.5) //task
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should trigger the timer on started to avoid the initial delay.

Comment: @dtech Thanks for notifying me of that detail, an elegant way to do what you're committing is to activate the triggeredOnStart property. :P

Comment: Also, `;`'s in QML are redundant unless you have multiple statements per line

Comment: Finally, I'd save a few lines of code by setting the timer `running: zoomIn.containsPress`, eliminating the need for the pressed and released handlers ;)

Comment: And they just keep on coming, you don't need a `{ }` block for signal handlers if they contain a single expression.

Comment: @dtech I understand that point, but my idea is that there must be repetitive task, it is only for educational purposes. :P

Comment: It is often beneficial to have such repetitive tasks implemented as stand alone functions rather than inside the handlers, and simply invoke the function via a one-liner. Also, if you use a named function, you can connect and disconnect, which can be very useful because unlike property bindings that get replaced on re-binding, signal handlers get stacked together, so the only way to remove previous or "inherited" handlers is to have them as named functions so you can disconnect them. Which is obviously impossible with anonymous expressions.

Comment: @dtech Okay, I understand, you're right, it's just what you recommend in the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals

Comment: I'd say that `pressed` is more fitting here than `containsMouse`

Comment: `pressed` will be true even if the cursor moves outside the mouse area, in this regard I'd say `containsPress` is more intuitive in the apparent usage scenario. My first comment featured `containsMouse ` but that was quickly revised to `containsPress`, however since comment changes do not auto-update, eyllanesc ended up taking the advice in its initial and suboptimal form. `containsMouse` will work just fine thou, unless you employ `hoverEnabled`.